# opencart view is not appropriate

Tags: php, ssl, view, opencart

I am not getting whats wrong with it when i enter just

[sharishari.com](http://sharishari.com)

it gives so many errors .you can have look.even add to cart also have a error.
And when i use http://www.sharishari.com
it works fine.What is the issue ?why i am getting nonfunctional view and errors in my web.My ssl is enabled from admin area of opencart.2.3.0.2
but i dont have godaddy ssl.is it because of ssl or what?Most people they just write domain name and enter.What if i write my domain name and enter it will go on sharishari.com and which is nonfunctional.need guidiance
Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Well it looks like the issue comes from non "www" version

I guess a simple fix would be to add

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

And your site will always open with www

Comment: where in opencart i should put this code .i am new in opencart .Will be very thankful to you.

Comment: https://codeshare.io/5Q8kz7 this is my .htaccess i tied to put your code in it it didnt work

Answer (score 0):

Check both of your config.php files, (root and /admin) and see if your paths are correct

starting at line 3

```
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://yourdomain.com/');

// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'https://yourdomain.com/');
```

If they have www before the domain, remove it.